# JQuery Displaying pop up inside pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, popup

I already have a JQuery function that creates a popup using an iframe. 
A new requirements says I need to create another popup triggered from the first popup but the iframe doesn't allow me to create another popup. Is there anyway I can create a popup using the main page as a parent instead of an iframe? please if you have a better suggestion, let me know. 
thanks

code:

```
function GetPopUp ("../folder/file.htm", "POPUP Title")
 {
   var xpos = mouse_x;
   var ypos = mouse_y;
   var windowID = $(href.split('/')).last()[0].split('.')[0];
   var $dialog = $("#" + windowID)

   var dimensions = GetPopUpDimensions(windowID);

   $('body').after('<iframe id="' + windowID + '" style="padding:0;" src="' + href +  '">  </iframe>');
   $dialog = $("#" + windowID)
   $dialog.dialog(
   {
    autoOpen: false,
    title: title,
    position: 'center',
    sticky: false,
    width: dimensions.DialogWidth,
    height: dimensions.DialogHeight,
    draggable: true,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    close: function () {
        $(this).dialog('destroy');
        $("#" + windowID).remove();
    }
});
$dialog.load(function () {
    $dialog.dialog('open');
    $dialog.css("width", "100%"); // reset the width that is set by jquery UI
});
```

}

The htm file has a clickable link that is expected to trigger another popup

Comment: can you post some code so we know what you mean by popup using iframe?

Comment: Please check the code above, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code is executing inside of the iframe you can prefix your DOM selector with:

```
window.parent.
```

Comment: Thanks Man, I used window.parent to call the function which creates the second popup and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The popup window will not apply to top of the IFrame window automatically, so we can easy to apply it through Parent.function_name();

function_name() => this function is defined top of the IFrame window. You can see the full demo at below link

[Click Here for demo](http://allinworld99.blogspot.com/2015/03/popup-inside-iframe-two-iframe-inside.html)